# Variance of SDE with two different definitons

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the SDE $$dX_t = \sigma X_t dB_t,$$
where $B_t$ is Brownian motion.
Ive calculated the solution to this SDE as
$$X_t = \exp(\sigma B_t-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t)X_0.$$ Then the expectation is
$$\mathbb{E}(X_t) = \exp(\sigma^2 t)X_0.$$
Now I want to calculate the variance. If I use the definition $Var(X_t)= \mathbb{E}[(X_t-\mathbb{E}(X_t))^2]$ then I get the following result:
\begin{align}
Var(X_t)&= \mathbb{E}[(\exp(\sigma B_t-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t)X_0 -\exp(\sigma^2 t)X_0)^2]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[X_0^2(\exp(2\sigma B_t - \sigma^2 t)-2^2 \exp(\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 t + \sigma B_t)+ \exp(2\sigma^2 t))]\\
&= X_0^2\exp(\sigma^2 t)(\exp(\sigma^2 t) -1)).
\end{align}

But if I use the definition $Var(X_t)=\mathbb{E}(X_t^2) - \mathbb{E}(X_t)^2$ then I get a reverse result, that is:
\begin{align}
Var(X_t)&=\mathbb{E}[(\exp(2\sigma B_t-\sigma^2t)X_0^2] - (\exp(\sigma^2 t)X_0)^2\\
&= X_0^2\exp(2\sigma^2 t - \sigma^2 t) - X_0^2 \exp(2 \sigma^2 t)\\
&= X_0^2(\exp(\sigma^2 t)-\exp(2\sigma^2 t))\\
&= X_0^2 \exp(\sigma^2 t)(1-\exp(\sigma^2 t)).
\end{align}

How can that be? Where am I making the mistake?
Im thankfull for any help..

Comment: I think you might want to double check your computation for $\mathbb{E}[X_t]$.  Since $dX_t = \sigma X_t dB_t$, $X$ is a martingale, so its expectation should be constant.

Comment: Please close this question by accepting the answer (use comments if it does not seem complete) and then ask a new question. (The edit history has archived the text of the new question.)

Comment: @sinem I posted a solution.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2):

If $dX_t=\sigma X_tdB_t$, then from Itoh's Lemma $d\log(X_t)=-\frac12 \sigma^2 dt + \sigma dB_t$ and $\log(X_t)$ is normally distributed with mean, $\mu=-\sigma^2/2$ and variance equal to $\sigma^2$.

The $k$'th moments of $X_t$ are given by $X_0^k e^{k(2\mu+k\sigma^2)/2}$.  Hence, $\mathbb{E}(X_t)=X_0$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_t^2)=X_0^2 e^{\sigma^2t}$

We can calculate the variance of $X_t$ as

$$\begin{align}
Var(X_t)&=\mathbb{E}((X_t-X_0)^2)\\\\
&=\mathbb{E}(X_t^2)-2X_0\mathbb{E}(X_t)+X_0^2\\\\
&=X_0^2e^{\sigma^2t}-2X_0^2+X_0^2\\\\
&=X_0^2(e^{\sigma^2t}-1)
\end{align}$$

Alternatively, we can compute the variance of $X_t$ as

$$\begin{align}
Var(X_t)&=\mathbb{E}(X_t^2) -X_0^2\\\\
&=X_0^2 e^{\sigma^2t}-X_0^2\\\\
&=X_0^2(e^{\sigma^2t}-1)
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: But the solution is $X_t = \exp(-1/2\sigma2 t + \sigma B_t)X_0$ so $\mathbb{E}(X_t^2) = \mathbb{E}((\exp(-\sigma^2 t + 2\sigma B_t)X_0^2) = \exp(-\sigma^2 t + \sigma^2 t)X_0^2 = X_0^2$ and not $X_0^2 \exp(\sigma^2 t)$.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is incorrect.  The second moment of $X_t$ is $X_0^2 e^{\sigma^2 t}$.  Why do you believe otherwise?

Comment: Is the solution $X_t=\exp(−\frac{1}{2}σ^2t+σB_t)X_0$ incorrect? i think this solution is correct. Square of this solution is $X_0^2 \exp(2\sigma B_t-\sigma^2 t)$ and then tak the expectation of it. Expectation of $uB_t$ is $\frac{1}{2}u^2 t$. So where is the mistake in my calculation?

Comment: Yes.  $X_t=X_0 e^{-\sigma^2 t/2 + \sigma B_t}$.  And $X_t^2=X_0^2 e^{-\sigma^2 t +2\sigma B_t}$.  And $\mathbb{E}(X_t)=X_0$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_t^2)=X_0^2 e^{\sigma^2 t}$.  Note $(2\sigma)^2/2 = 2\sigma^2$ and $2\sigma^2-\sigma^2=\sigma^2$.  Does that help clarify?

Comment: Ah yesss thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.